# changed logic when click on Antd Tab REACT

Tags: reactjs, tabs, antd

I'm using antd version 3 and want to change the outcome onChange  when Tab is clicked.
Here the picture of my desire objective [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMhF8.png)

My tab title has a checkbox. Outcome should be in this way: when user is stand at Tab1 should have a possibility to change value checkbox of Tab2 or Tab3 without setting active Tab or moving to Tab2 or Tab3. I have read that tab didn't support HOC... I tried a lot of ways to solve but didn't work out with that. event.PreventDefault / event.stopPropagation similarly result. Even if handlers like onTabClick / onChange didn't set active Tab with a new key after checked checkbox active key is old but tab is render with new information.

Here example of custom tab title component with some extract from code

```
    <Tabs
     defaultActiveKey={'Tab 1'}
     onChange={(key) => onChangeHandler(key)}
     onTabClick={(key: string, event: MouseEvent) => onTabClick(key, event)}
    >
        <TabPane
          tab={<Header name={'Tab1'} />}
          key={'Tab 1'}
        />
        <TabPane
          tab={<Header name={'Tab 2'}  />}
          key={'Tab 2'}
        />
        <TabPane
          tab={<Header name={'Tab 3'} />}
          key={'Tab 3'}
        />
```

```
    const Header = ({
     name,
     onChange,
     isActive,
     id,
     }) => {
     return (
        <div>
            <Checkbox
            isActive={isActive}
            value={id}
            checked={isActive}
            onChange={onChange}
            />
            <Title >{name}</Title>
        </div>
       )
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want the tabs not to change when you click on the check box.
To do this, you can pass the `onClick` function to the `Checkbox` and stop the event bubbling there

```
const Header = ({ name, onChange, isActive, id }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Checkbox
        isActive={isActive}
        value={id}
        checked={isActive}
        onChange={onChange}
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.stopPropagation();
        }}
      />
      <Title>{name}</Title>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: onChange for checkbox is starting after Tab's onTabClick && onChange